# Defining a drawable with a layer-list that has an item at half the height

Tags: android, android-widget

I have implemented the following button style in my drawable folder:

```
<layer-list
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >
        <item>
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"
                >
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF666666" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" 
                    />
                <solid
                    android:color="#FF000000" 
                    />  
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:bottom="22dp" android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp"
            >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"
                >
                <corners
                    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/corner_radius" android:topRightRadius="@dimen/corner_radius" 
                    />
                <solid
                    android:color="#10FFFFFF" 
                    />
            </shape>            
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

My problem is I would like to set the second item at half the height, relatively, not absolutely. You can see that I set it with 'android:bottom="22dp"' here because my button is usually 45dp in height. However, I would like the second item to be always at half the height, whatever the height of my button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do this programmatically.

1. Give both the layer-list and the second item `android:id` attributes.
2. Use `getResouces().getDrawable()` to obtain references to both the layer-list and the second item. Be sure to cast the layer-list to a `LayerDrawable`.
3. You may have to call `Drawable.mutate()` on the `LayerDrawable` and second item `Drawable`.
4. Get the button height and use `Drawable.setBounds()` to modify the drawing rect for the second layer accordingly.
5. Use `LayerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId()` to replace the updated `Drawable` in your layer-list.
6. Apply the LayerDrawable to your button.

Answer (score 3):

With @Tyler's help, I found an easier way to do this:

```
LayerDrawable layerList = (LayerDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_background).mutate();                
btnBlackLayerList.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, btnHeight/2);
btn.setBackground(layerList);
```